# Can't redefine page style in book class

Tags: fancyhdr

I have derived a class from the standard book class.
I want to redefine the header and footers. But if I use the following code

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[L]{\PageWaveHeader}
\fancyfoot[L]{\PageBox\PageWaveFoot}
```

I see no changes. The header and footer are just empty.

The strange thing is that if I redefine the plain style

```
\pagestyle{plain}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[L]{\PageWaveHeader}
\fancyfoot[L]{\PageBox\PageWaveFoot}
}
```

the chapter opening pages looks fine (as defined above).

Does someone see what is the problem with the first code?

EDIT: Adding a MWE (not so minimal)

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% page size
\RequirePackage{geometry}
% hegight 265mm width 202 % it looks like letter size
\geometry{%
    paper=letterpaper,
    includefoot,
    outer=16mm, % TODO CHECK
    inner=16mm,
    bottom=2.4pc,
    top=17mm,
    head=14.5pt,
    headsep=0mm
}


\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usepgflibrary{shadings}
%\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
%\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\definecolor{fillblue}{cmyk}{0.16,0.03,0,0.03}
\definecolor{chaptercolor}{cmyk}{0,0.76,0.49,0.07}

\definecolor{partcolor}{cmyk}{0,1,0,0}

%% FOOTER
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand\PageBox{%
\tikz[baseline,trim left=0mm,trim right=0mm,remember picture, overlay] {
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
    \node [
        fill=fillblue,
        text = black,
        anchor= base east,
        minimum width=10mm,
        minimum height=7mm] (a) at (0mm,0) {\sffamily\thepage};
\end{pgfonlayer}
    }%   
}%
%

\newcommand\PageWaveFoot{%
\tikz[remember picture,overlay] {
\coordinate (low west) at ($(current page.south west) +(0, 0.5cm)$); 
\coordinate (low east) at ($(current page.south west)+(\paperwidth, 0.5cm)$);
    \fill[
        partcolor,
]  decorate[snake, segment length=\paperwidth/2]{ (low west) -- (low east)}  -- (current page.south east) -- (current page.south west) -- (low west);
    }%   
}%

\newcommand\PageWaveHeader{%
\tikz[remember picture, overlay] {
\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
\coordinate (up west) at ($(current page.north west) +(0, -0.5cm)$); 
\coordinate (up east) at ($(current page.north west)+(\paperwidth, -0.5cm)$);
    \fill[
        partcolor,
]  decorate[snake, segment length=\paperwidth/2]{ (up west) -- (up east)}  -- (current page.north east) -- (current page.north west) -- (up west);
\end{pgfonlayer}
}%   
}%


\pagestyle{headings}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[L]{\PageWaveHeader}
\fancyfoot[L]{\PageBox\PageWaveFoot}
}



\begin{document}
\chapter{A test}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not without a MWE.

Comment: how have you derived your class? Usually `book.cls` uses `\pagestyle{headings}` in the last few lines.

Comment: Sorry @egreg, The real question was if the first code block looks ok. I am working on the MWE. I `\LoadClass[]{book}`.

Comment: Yes, it seems correct, so there must be something else that doesn't apply the page style.

Comment: you are using `\pagestyle{headings}` this is the book defaut, so what you need?

Comment: if you replace `\pagestyle{headings}` by your `fancy` code it will be fine

Comment: @touhami Sorry I did not understand clearly. Should I change `headings` and `plain` by `fancy`? It is not working. I get the usual headings style.

Comment: No, just replace `\pagestyle{headings}` by 5 lines in top of your question `\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyhead[L]{\PageWaveHeader}
\fancyfoot[L]{\PageBox\PageWaveFoot}`

Comment: @touhami Looks like an answer?

Comment: @touhami Not really :-( The MWE is working fine, but the full document is not working. I still need to more in detail.